# mySQL arrange by certain ID. Missing a row of data

Tags: php, mysql

PHP mySQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id < 3, id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$work = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

RESULT in mySQL:

```
3  Shawn
4  Ryan
5  Seth
1  Joe
2  Craig
```

PHP:

```
<?php while ($work = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <p> <?php echo $work['id']; ?> </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

RESULT:

```
4
5
1
2
```

I'm missing the id that I want my data to start with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think your SQL statement should be : `SELECT * FROM table_name Where id<3 ORDER BY id`

Comment: Why not add `SELECT *, IF(id < 3, 1, 0) as ``is_less_than_X`` FROM table_name ORDER BY id < 3, id`? I don't know what you're doing with the list, but this might be useful? You can also put an `IF` statement in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @AVD The op want all the results, not just `id<3`, but order by `id<3` which is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did `$work = mysql_fetch_array($result);` once before the while loop, your cursor begins from the second row.